# Can't install Ubuntu from USB

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, boot, usb

Coming from Windows 10, I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

My current system specifications:

- Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon (4th generation)
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz (4 CPUs), 2.2GHz
- 64-bit
- UEFI

With the software Rufus, I created a bootable USB drive, from the official Ubuntu ISO (ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso). I used the following settings:

> Device: Kingston 64 GB USB
>
> Boot selection: ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
>
> Partition scheme: GPT
>
> Target system: UEFI (non CSM)
>
> File system: NTFS
>
> Cluster size: 4096 bytes (Default)

I have disabled Secure Boot and Fast Startup.

When booting up, and getting to the menu, where I choose which to boot from, I get the following choices:

> Windows Boot Manager
>
> ubuntu
>
> ATA HDD0
>
> USB HDD: Kingston DataTraveler 3.0
>
> PCI LAN

Pressing "ubuntu" refreshes the menu, almost like it tries to start something. Nothing happens, . Pressing "USB HDD: Kingston DataTraveler 3.0", opens GNU GRUB, where I don't know what to do. I suppose pressing "ubuntu" should be the normal way to install?

Does anyone know what goes wrong here?

Comment: What options do you have available without the USB drive plugged in?

Comment: Ubuntu installation ISO works after just `dd`-ing to USB, without creating a filesystem beforehand. I believe Rufus provides an option to "`dd` image to USB" or similar. This should be your first choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Rufus, select MBR partition scheme, FAT32 filesystem.
Those settings are for the Ubuntu USB image, not instalation on your computer.

Comment: already did that. Having the same problem